# React Native iOS App Perfectly Runs on Simulator and Physical Devices but Crashes on App Store Release - RCTFormatError on iPad with iOS 17.1.2

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store-connect

Application is running perfectly on Physical Device and Simulator(IOS and iPad), But On Appstore release it crashed.

**Symbolicating Error Log :**

RCTFormatError (in MyApp) (RCTAssert.m:167) -[RCTExceptionsManager reportFatal:stack:exceptionId:extraDataAsJSON:] (in MyApp) (RCTExceptionsManager.mm:82) -[RCTExceptionsManager reportException:] (in MyApp) (RCTExceptionsManager.mm:154) -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] (in MyApp) (RCTModuleMethod.mm:587) facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&, int, (anonymous namespace)::SchedulingContext) (in MyApp) (RCTNativeModule.mm:197) invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int) (in MyApp) (RCTNativeModule.mm:105) main (in MyApp) (main.m:8) FIRCLSTerminateHandler() (in MyApp) (FIRCLSException.mm:0) FIRCLSMachExceptionServer (in MyApp) (FIRCLSMachException.c:168) +[RCTCxxBridge runRunLoop] (in MyApp) (RCTCxxBridge.mm:0) facebook::hermes::inspector::detail::SerialExecutor::runLoop() (in MyApp) (SerialExecutor.cpp:41) void* std::__1::__thread_proxy[abi:v160006]<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_deletestd::__1::__thread_struct>, void ()(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator>, std::__1::function<void ()>), std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator>, std::__1::function<void ()>>>(void) (in MyApp) (thread:299) facebook::hermes::inspector::detail::SerialExecutor::runLoop() (in MyApp) (SerialExecutor.cpp:41) void* std::__1::__thread_proxy[abi:v160006]<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_deletestd::__1::__thread_struct>, void ()(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator>, std::__1::function<void ()>), std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator>, std::__1::function<void ()>>>(void) (in MyApp) (thread:299) facebook::hermes::inspector::detail::SerialExecutor::runLoop() (in MyApp) (SerialExecutor.cpp:41) void* std::__1::__thread_proxy[abi:v160006]<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_deletestd::__1::__thread_struct>, void ()(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator>, std::__1::function<void ()>), std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator>, std::__1::function<void ()>>>(void) (in MyApp) (thread:299) facebook::hermes::inspector::detail::SerialExecutor::runLoop() (in MyApp) (SerialExecutor.cpp:41) void* std::__1::__thread_proxy[abi:v160006]<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_deletestd::__1::__thread_struct>, void ()(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator>, std::__1::function<void ()>), std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator>, std::__1::function<void ()>>>(void) (in MyApp) (thread:299) STDERR:

Replacing matches in sample/spindump report: 2 MyApp 0x10531419c 0x104f54000 + 3932572 Replacing matches in sample/spindump report: 3 MyApp 0x104f6bcd4 0x104f54000 + 97492 Replacing matches in sample/spindump report: 4 MyApp 0x104f6c4e8 0x104f54000 + 99560 Replacing matches in sample/spindump report: 8 MyApp 0x105343b3c 0x104f54000 + 4127548 Replacing matches in sample/spindump report: 9 MyApp 0x105345b8c 0x104f54000 + 4135820 Replacing matches in sample/spindump report: 10 MyApp 0x1053457dc 0x104f54000 + 4134876 Replacing matches in sample/spindump report: 10 MyApp 0x104f5a8bc 0x104f54000 + 26812 Replacing matches in sample/spindump report: 7 MyApp 0x104fd6820 0x104f54000 + 534560 Replacing matches in sample/spindump report: 4 MyApp 0x104fdf198 0x104f54000 + 569752 Replacing matches in sample/spindump report: 7 MyApp 0x105326414 0x104f54000 + 4006932 Replacing matches in sample/spindump report: 3 MyApp 0x1057c64d8 0x104f54000 + 8856792 Replacing matches in sample/spindump report: 4 MyApp 0x105787e08 0x104f54000 + 8601096 Replacing matches in sample/spindump report: 3 MyApp 0x1057c64d8 0x104f54000 + 8856792 Replacing matches in sample/spindump report: 4 MyApp 0x105787e08 0x104f54000 + 8601096 Replacing matches in sample/spindump report: 3 MyApp 0x1057c64d8 0x104f54000 + 8856792 Replacing matches in sample/spindump report: 4 MyApp 0x105787e08 0x104f54000 + 8601096 Replacing matches in sample/spindump report: 3 MyApp 0x1057c64d8 0x104f54000 + 8856792 Replacing matches in sample/spindump report: 4 MyApp

**Please advise.

thank you have a good day.**

I have update my  all node_modules, but still its not working .

Comment: Hi Kushal, did you find the solution?